# Material app in Column with regular sized navigation bar

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to display an Image on top of my entire app. So I Placed an image and my dashboard in a column in Main.dart file

My `main.dart` file.

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {   
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new MaterialApp(
        home: new Scaffold(
          body: new SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Image.asset('assets/ads.png'),
                new Expanded(
                  child: Dashboard(),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

and `Dashboard.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Books')),
        body: new Container(
          child: new Center(
            child: new Text('data'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, this code generates output like this.

[image]

I need regular sized Appar. This AppBar is really big. Can someone suggest what's wrong here?

Comment: Try to remove `MaterialApp` from `_DashboardState`. Make it like: `return Scaffold(.....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do Like This :-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/350x100"),
              new Expanded(
                child: Dashboard(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Books')),
        body: new Container(
          child: new Center(
            child: new Text('data'),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]